# GA4 user demographics to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have recently connected my GA4 to BigQuery which is working great. However, I can't find how to query the age and gender of my users. I do see reports of age and gender in my GA4 environment, so I am aware that it does collect this data. I found some other posts mentioning that it isn't possible to have these detailed demographics be exported to BigQuery. However, these posts and its answers were 2 years ago. I was wondering whether it is possible nowadays to export these user demographics to BigQuery, and if it is possible, how to do this.

I tried researching the internet and ask ChatGPT about this, but I'm unable to find clear instructions on how to do it. I'm also unable to find clear explanation of why it wouldn't be possible to export the user demographics to BigQuery. The most occuring explanation I found explained that privacy is the reason that the user demographics aren't shown in BigQuery.

Thanks in advance!